# Understanding "What in pollination?" meme

Tags: word-meaning, jokes

I came across many images on Twitter like this
[image]
**update 1**
[Original link.](https://twitter.com/Dory/status/835259178348347392?s=09)

Does the hat resemble nation? If yes then what's the reason?
I came to know that everything that ends with nation or sounds like nation they use this sticker and laugh at it. 
But I don't get the joke.

Comment: did you look up the definition for **pollination**? Do you recognize the creature as a bee?

Comment: Also, do you know Dory is a blue tang fish and where they live?

Comment: @WillowRex it has got nothing to do with pollination and I looked up the definition for pollination and I know the creature of bee.

Comment: it is a play on words, the hat may or may not be important, it is part of the theme.

Comment: FWIW, it's hardly a joke, [since it's IMO too much of a forced joke](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/naked-banana) - jokes, by definition, should be amusing... this one (arguably) ain't.

Comment: @vaxquis but 20.8 people liked it on Twitter and many understood it. So, it's worth asking why people are laughing.

Comment: @AshutoshSoni I never said it's *not worth asking* - it's always good to ask. 20.8k people ain't much compared to how many people laugh at Amy Schumer's jokes... and they humour value has been argued anyway (google 'amy schumer south park' FWIW). It's just that this "what in pollination" meme is a forced and obscure rip-off of another obscure-ish meme, resulting in something that is, well, quite forced and obscure in general. The joke value in the original was high, since it was original & amusing doge-style humour. Many of the rip-offs were quite good too. This one is, IMO, so-so at best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The joke is that this is a parody of another popluar meme.
From knowyourmeme.com, [What in Tarnation](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/what-in-tarnation),
[image]

"When you find a city slicker on FarmersOnly.com / wot n ternation"

> **About**
>   “What in Tarnation?” is a rhetorical question meaning “what in damnation?”, which is often associated with Americans living in the Southern United States expressing incredulous bewilderment.

The meme above spawned many parody memes. Here are some of the memes.
[image]

[image]

Notice that the parodies have the hat in common, follow the formula *what in X* where X rhymes with *tarnation*, and the image is somehow related to X.

In the OP, notice that the image is of a bee, bees pollinate, and the act of pollinating is **pollination**.

Answer (score 1):

Like with many jokes, one needs to know several different cultural things.

The usual phrase is

> What in [tarnation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tarnation)?

and stereotypically it is used by cowboys in their accent.

It means "What in the world?" used to show surprise for something very unexpected.

> pollination

sounds very similar to "tarnation"

The cowboy hat is on a bee and bees are know for pollinating plants, not for wearing cowboy hats. So, Dory is *misspeaking* which she is known to do from time to time, since she plays a ditzy character.